# Xidel extract data inside the tag -- raw output

Tags: html, linux, bash, parsing, xidel

Pleased to be member of StackOverflow, a long time lurker in here.

I need to parse text between two tags, so far I've found a wonderful tool called [Xidel](http://www.videlibri.de/xidel.html)

I need to parse text in between

```html
<div class="description">
Text. <tag>Also tags.</tag> More text.
</div>
```

However, said text can include HTML tags in it, and I want them to be printed out in raw format. So using a command like:

```
xidel --xquery '//div[@class="description"]' file.html
```

Gets me:

```
Text. Also tags. More text.
```

And I need it to be exactly as it is, so:

```
Text. <tag>Also tags.</tag> More text.
```

How can I achieve this?

Regards, R

Answer (score 4):

Can be done in a couple of ways with Xidel, which is why I love it so much.

HTML-templating:

```
xidel -s file.html -e "<div class='description'>{inner-html()}</div>"
```

XPath:

```
xidel -s file.html -e "//div[@class='description']/inner-html()"
```

CSS:

```
xidel -s file.html -e "inner-html(css('div.description'))"
```

BTW, on Linux: swap the double quotes for single and vice versa.

Comment: The command from "HTML-templating" extract only first occurrence. How to extract all occurrences? Consder multiple `<div class='description'>`. How to process all of them?

Answer (score 1):

You can show the tags by adding the `--output-format=xml` option.

```
xidel --xquery '//div[@class="description"]' --output-format=xml file.html
```

Comment: This creates a new xml-template for a file, including the `<div class="description">` tag itself. I highly doubt that's what **RomanM** wanted.